# Prepare UIImage with lots of layers on background thread

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have the problem that I have some really big UIScrollView and tons of images loaded on it as user scrolls. Images are stored on the device, however I receive information from server what to display on particular part of UIScrollView. When user scrolls a bit I need to show images at new position as I cannot afford to draw whole UIScrollView with images at startup. For the background I had one relatively small image which I move throughout the View. But the problem is that on top of that background I should draw a lot of UIImage objects(about 300-400) which are not particulary bih however are separeted on layers(one image on top of other on top of other etc.). Blocking scrolling while drawing is NOT an option.

Now I'm trying to decide which approach will suite my best:

1. Add all needed images to UIView on background thread and then just add UIView to ScrollView on main thread(which hopefully wont take long). Here when scroll somewhere I will need to calculate and create new UIView with objects and position it next to existing and eventualy to remove first UIView with all objects and layers when user continues to scroll in some direction.
2. Combine all layers in image with CoreGraphics and present them as objects with already decided layers. In this way I can remove specific object(image) from scroll view. When user scrolls I just create new objects and add them to view as full objects, and can remove objects when user scrolls enough instead of removing whole view. The problem here is adding multiple objects to UIScrollView on main thread, however when they are combined they won't be more than 15-20 objects.

My biggest concerns are performance and threading. As I said I cannot block main thread(or let's say cannot do this for a time that user will notice) and cannot combine images at my graphics department as they have tons of variatons which are decided at runtime. That's why I'm thinking of a way to prepare data on background thread and just really fast add it on main thread instead of preparing and adding it on main thread(which will block UI).

Every help will be greatly appriciated!

Regards,

hris.to

Answer (score 0):

Look at using CATiledLayer for a UIView backing.  It is was designed for this.

I have a map that has one UIView in a UIScrollView and the UIView is sized to the full size of the entire map.  The CATiledLayer handles when to draw each tile of the view.

Comment: Please do not use Stack Overflow to promote your website through links; answers should only include relevant code, not links to other sites.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables thanks for the heads up!  I will be sure to not do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm writing here just to let you know how I fix my issue.

Main problem was that I was moving a background picture while scrolling(so I don't load an enormous file) and while doing that I was fetching information from server and try to draw on the same tiles which makes system crash with well known crash:

```
CALayer was muted while enumerated
```

I was depending on performSelector method along with @synchronized but it turns out that this is not effective and sometimes two threads(main UI thread and background thread) were trying to change same tiles on screen. So basically what I did is to change background fetching and drawing from:

```
[self performSelectorOnBackgroundThread]
```

to using concrete background thread, to which I store reference:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSThread* backgroundThread;
```

And now each time I need to load new tiles or I need to move background, I'm cancelling this thread(and make sure it's cancelled) before start any other operation. Also there was a little problem when switching between view with this thread and other views, as my thread hangs, and I needed to set a timeout:

```
[_backgroundThread cancel];

int currentAttempts = 0;
while( [_backgroundThread isExecuting] )
{
    if( currentAttempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS_TO_CANCEL_THREAD )
    {
        //make sure we dont hang and force background
        _backgroundThread = nil;
        return;
    }

    [_backgroundThread cancel];
    currentAttempts++;
}
```

In my 'scrollViewDidScroll' however, I didn't use the recursion as this results in slight UI blocks while scrolling on older devices(such as iPhone 4) which is unacceptable. So there I basically just cancel the thread and hope to get cancelled quick enough(which with dozens of tests appears to be working):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    [_backgroundThread cancel];

    //move background around
    [self moveBackground];
}
```

Downside of this approach is that you need lots of check in your background thread as calling 'cancel' to it **won't actually cancel anything**. As per apple docs it'll only change isCancelled state of your thread and you are responsible to make this thread quit in basically the same way as it'll quit normally(so the system has a chance to cleanup after your thread):

```
if( [_backgroundThread isCancelled] )
{
    return;
}
```

Regards,

hris.to